# Time scheduling algorithm based on history

Tags: algorithm

I have been trying for some time solve a scheduling problem for an App that I used to work at. This problem is as follows...

Example Scenario:

**ContactA** is running Our App in the background.  He just got into his car for his commute home.  So, he is in @Evening Commute status.

His Valet settings state that he only wants to be notified to make Phone Calls when in @Evening Commute status (no text or email reminders).

Once Our app sees **ContactA** is in @Evening Commute status, and that he is available to make Phone Calls, the app will scan ALL his contacts to find any contacts that he has specified as preferred to Call.

Th algorithm identifies 3 potential matches for **ContactA** in his Agent list:

- ContactX
- ContactY
- ContactZ

How does it decide which one to prompt **ContactA** to connect with during his @Evening Commute?

First, it should look to see if any of those three are using The app too.  For example, it identifies that **ContactX** and **ContactY** are both using The app, but **ContactZ** is not.

So, it will then look further at **ContactX** and **ContactY** to see if either of them are currently in a Valet status that is accepting Phone Calls.

If both are, it will look to see if either is a Favorite.  If so, that person takes priority.

If neither are, it can look back at history to see which is the oldest in terms of last contacted to choose which one to contact first.

If both **ContactX** and **ContactY** are showing as “unavailable” right now, based on their App Valet settings, the app could choose to prompt me to call **ContactZ**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You actually described the algorithm in your question, what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: If there is any ready type of algorithm to solve this?

Comment: You described the algorithm yourself. Just translate it into code, step by step, there's no magic there. I also do not see how the question is related to the title of the question ("history").

Comment: Thanks, Let's supposed that this algorithm do the calcul that for the contactA this result must be stored so we can use it to suggest to contactX and ContactY and ContactZ. Means optimized the calcul.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode (you did not ask for any specific language, but this is a simple implementation of your algorithm in code). contactsSpecified would be an array of all contacts "specified as preferred to Call".

```
var contactsToCall[];
//Add all contacts that are using the app and are available
foreach(contact in contactsSepcified) {
    if(contact.isUsingApp() && contact.isAvailable()) {
        contactsToCall.add(contact);
    }
}

//Add all contacts not using the app if none of the app users have been added
if(contactsToCall.size() == 0) {
    foreach(contact in contactsSepcified) {
        if(!contact.isUsingApp()) {
            contactsToCall.add(contact);
        }
    }
}

foreach(contact in conctactsToCall) {
    if(conctact.isFavorite()) {
        call(contact);
        return;
    }
}

suggestContacts(contactsToCall);
```

Comment: Many thanks. the issue with this approach we not saving the result to use it for other contact. may already contactsToCall for ContactA so for optimzing the calcul for other contacts inside contactsToCall.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your comment.

Comment: The app still monitoring contact status. This mean if there is 4 contacts we should suggest for each the best time to contact someone.  if the calcul is already done for the contact1 so we must saving this calcul to not repeat it for the contact2, contact3 and contact4.